# How to remove a broken qemu / kvm container?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, containers

I'm running some containers on my server (qemu kvm, libvirt).
A few of them are totally broken and I am unable to remove them by any means. Have been googlin for half a day, but just can't find a working solution.

I have tried removing the broken containers using `virsh` and `prlctl` commands. Can't reinstall them either. Even tried deleting the container files by hand, but no luck. `virsh` does not even see the containers and `prlctl` gives me errors like `Failed to get VM config: Operation failed. Failed to execute the operation`.

```
# prlctl list -a
{uuid1}  stopped      -               CT my-ct1
{uuid2}  invalid      -               CT my-ct2
```

How can I completely remove these containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, looks like I was able to remove these CTs by deleting their home dirs in /var/vz/private/UUID_of_CT/ and config files in /etc/vz/conf/UUD_of_CT.conf and then a full server reboot. After that, they dissapeared from prlctl list -a.